# Fill some cells in the column with special word

Tags: r

I have data like that (it's just couple of rows from my data):

```
> dput(head(data_met))
structure(list(X = c(3L, 19L, 28L, 33L, 34L, 35L), Pathway = c(0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), Gene.name = structure(1:6, .Label = c("AT1G01090", 
"AT1G02500", "AT1G03130", "AT1G03330", "AT1G03475", "AT1G03630", 
"AT1G04410", "AT1G06410", "AT1G06570", "AT1G06680", "AT1G07370", 
"AT1G07780", "AT1G08490"), class = "factor"), X1_1 = c(0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0), X1_2 = c(0, 0, 0, 1.133759575, 0, 0), X1_3 = c(0, 
1.389359906, 0, 0, 1, 0), X1_4 = c(0, 0.628125036, 0, 1.161302798, 
1, 0), X1_5 = c(0, 1.231056083, 0, 0.50892594, 0.01594858, 0), 
    X1_6 = c(0.186450525, 1, 0, 0.514811996, 0, 0), X1_7 = c(0, 
    1.149134552, 0, 0, 0, 0), X1_8 = c(0.105799533, 0.386877662, 
    0, 0, 0, 0), X1_9 = c(0.763452684, 0.554554123, 0, 0, 0, 
    0), X1_10 = c(0.979400044, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), X1_11 = c(1.120768885, 
    0.274641072, 0, 0, 0, 0.690696043), X1_12 = c(1, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0), X1_13 = c(1.276209448, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), X1_14 = c(0.970143925, 
    0, 1, 0, 0, 0), X1_15 = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), X1_16 = c(0.85529218, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 1), X1_17 = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), X1_18 = c(1.018244397, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0), X1_19 = c(2.138711024, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), X1_20 = c(0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), X1_21 = c(1.554696031, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0
    ), X1_22 = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), X1_23 = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L), X1_24 = c(1.681551744, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1.309303957
    )), .Names = c("X", "Pathway", "Gene.name", "X1_1", "X1_2", 
"X1_3", "X1_4", "X1_5", "X1_6", "X1_7", "X1_8", "X1_9", "X1_10", 
"X1_11", "X1_12", "X1_13", "X1_14", "X1_15", "X1_16", "X1_17", 
"X1_18", "X1_19", "X1_20", "X1_21", "X1_22", "X1_23", "X1_24"
), row.names = c(NA, 6L), class = "data.frame")
```

There is one column at the begining called "Pathway" full of 0. I would like to fill some of the rows with word ("aa_metabolism"). The list of rows which I want to fill can be find in this vector:

```
   > dput(aa)
c("AT1G02500", "AT1G07780", "AT1G09780", "AT1G09795", "AT1G12230", 
"AT1G13440", "AT1G14810", "AT1G15710", "AT1G16300", "AT1G17290", 
"AT1G17745", "AT1G18500", "AT1G18640", "AT1G23310", "AT1G25220", 
"AT1G31180", "AT1G31230", "AT1G31860", "AT1G32440", "AT1G48850", 
"AT1G48860", "AT1G54100", "AT1G56190", "AT1G58080", "AT1G62800", 
"AT1G65930", "AT1G70580", "AT1G71920", "AT1G72330", "AT1G72810", 
"AT1G74030", "AT1G74040", "AT1G75330", "AT1G79550", "AT1G80560", 
"AT1G80600", "AT2G01140", "AT2G01290", "AT2G04400", "AT2G05710", 
"AT2G17130", "AT2G17265", "AT2G17630", "AT2G19940", "AT2G21170", 
"AT2G21330", "AT2G22250", "AT2G22480", "AT2G27820", "AT2G29560", 
"AT2G29690", "AT2G30970", "AT2G31810", "AT2G36230", "AT2G36460", 
"AT2G36530", "AT2G36580", "AT2G36880", "AT2G37500", "AT2G39800", 
"AT2G42790", "AT2G43090", "AT2G43100", "AT2G43750", "AT2G44040", 
"AT2G44350", "AT2G45290", "AT2G45300", "AT2G45440", "AT3G01120", 
"AT3G03780", "AT3G04120", "AT3G04520", "AT3G04790", "AT3G04940", 
"AT3G06350", "AT3G07630", "AT3G08590", "AT3G09810", "AT3G10050", 
"AT3G12780", "AT3G13110", "AT3G14390", "AT3G17390", "AT3G17820", 
"AT3G19480", "AT3G19710", "AT3G22960", "AT3G23940", "AT3G29200", 
"AT3G48560", "AT3G49680", "AT3G50520", "AT3G52930", "AT3G52990", 
"AT3G53580", "AT3G54640", "AT3G55440", "AT3G55610", "AT3G57050", 
"AT3G57560", "AT3G58610", "AT3G58990", "AT3G59760", "AT3G59890", 
"AT3G60750", "AT3G60880", "AT3G61440", "AT4G01850", "AT4G02610", 
"AT4G08870", "AT4G08900", "AT4G13430", "AT4G13930", "AT4G14880", 
"AT4G17830", "AT4G19710", "AT4G23600", "AT4G24830", "AT4G26390", 
"AT4G26530", "AT4G26900", "AT4G26970", "AT4G29220", "AT4G29840", 
"AT4G31990", "AT4G32520", "AT4G33510", "AT4G33680", "AT4G34200", 
"AT4G35260", "AT4G35630", "AT4G35830", "AT4G37670", "AT4G37930", 
"AT4G38220", "AT4G38970", "AT4G39980", "AT5G03290", "AT5G05730", 
"AT5G08570", "AT5G10870", "AT5G10920", "AT5G11520", "AT5G11880", 
"AT5G13280", "AT5G13420", "AT5G14060", "AT5G14200", "AT5G14590", 
"AT5G14800", "AT5G16290", "AT5G17920", "AT5G17990", "AT5G19550", 
"AT5G20980", "AT5G22620", "AT5G26780", "AT5G28020", "AT5G28030", 
"AT5G35630", "AT5G36160", "AT5G37600", "AT5G38530", "AT5G44520", 
"AT5G48220", "AT5G52920", "AT5G53460", "AT5G54810", "AT5G56350", 
"AT5G56630", "AT5G57850", "AT5G57890", "AT5G61410", "AT5G61580", 
"AT5G63680", "AT5G63890", "AT5G65780", "AT5G66120")
```

Those names can be found in second column of my `data.frame` which I want to fill. Name of this column is "Gene.name".

Added:

Second vector/metabolism:

```
> dput(rnadegrad)
c("AT1G03330", "AT1G21190", "AT1G26230", "AT1G49760", "AT1G54490", 
"AT1G55490", "AT1G65700", "AT1G74030", "AT1G75660", "AT2G06990", 
"AT2G17510", "AT2G23350", "AT2G25355", "AT2G29560", "AT2G33210", 
"AT2G36530", "AT2G43810", "AT2G45810", "AT3G03710", "AT3G13300", 
"AT3G13470", "AT3G13860", "AT3G23990", "AT3G52150", "AT3G60500", 
"AT3G61240", "AT3G61620", "AT4G00660", "AT4G34110", "AT4G37910", 
"AT5G27720", "AT5G35430", "AT5G48870", "AT5G56500")
```

MAin table (some more rows):

```
> dput(tbl_test)
structure(list(X = c(3L, 19L, 28L, 33L, 34L, 35L, 45L, 66L, 69L, 
72L, 79L, 82L, 88L, 89L, 90L, 101L, 103L, 107L, 108L, 114L, 115L, 
129L, 137L, 138L, 155L, 169L, 171L, 179L, 186L, 189L, 195L, 200L, 
205L, 214L, 216L, 217L, 222L, 224L, 229L, 233L, 234L, 239L, 258L, 
261L, 262L, 266L, 271L, 272L, 277L, 279L, 285L, 301L, 306L, 320L, 
324L, 327L, 334L, 337L, 341L, 342L, 348L, 351L, 360L, 391L, 397L, 
401L, 402L, 411L, 416L, 429L, 436L, 439L, 444L, 450L, 453L, 456L, 
457L, 459L, 466L, 472L, 484L, 488L, 493L, 498L, 508L, 515L, 519L, 
529L, 540L, 546L, 548L, 555L, 556L, 557L, 575L, 579L, 584L, 585L, 
589L, 601L, 604L, 606L, 610L, 620L, 621L, 624L, 625L, 630L, 641L, 
643L, 685L, 692L, 710L, 711L, 713L, 717L, 729L, 741L, 748L, 751L, 
758L, 770L, 780L, 783L, 787L, 788L, 802L, 806L, 808L, 814L, 817L, 
823L, 827L, 831L, 833L, 836L, 845L, 850L, 854L, 861L, 863L, 868L, 
871L, 879L, 898L, 899L, 900L, 917L, 918L, 920L, 926L, 937L, 946L, 
969L, 972L, 973L, 974L, 975L, 977L, 984L, 995L, 1008L, 1013L, 
1014L, 1019L, 1040L, 1045L, 1046L, 1053L, 1057L, 1064L, 1069L, 
1070L, 1079L, 1080L, 1081L, 1088L, 1100L, 1109L, 1112L, 1132L, 
1136L, 1138L, 1142L, 1146L, 1148L, 1154L, 1158L, 1160L, 1165L, 
1168L, 1171L, 1184L, 1187L, 1199L, 1208L, 1213L, 1220L, 1225L
), Pathway = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), Gene.name = structure(1:199, .Label = c("AT1G01090", 
"AT1G02500", "AT1G03130", "AT1G03330", "AT1G03475", "AT1G03630", 
"AT1G04410", "AT1G06410", "AT1G06570", "AT1G06680", "AT1G07370", 
"AT1G07780", "AT1G08490", "AT1G08520", "AT1G08550", "AT1G09430", 
"AT1G09620", "AT1G09780", "AT1G09795", "AT1G10590", "AT1G10670", 
"AT1G11870", "AT1G12230", "AT1G12240", "AT1G13440", "AT1G14610", 
"AT1G14810", "AT1G15710", "AT1G16300", "AT1G16460", "AT1G17050", 
"AT1G17290", "AT1G17745", "AT1G18500", "AT1G18590", "AT1G18640", 
"AT1G19920", "AT1G20020", "AT1G20340", "AT1G20620", "AT1G20630", 
"AT1G21190", "AT1G22940", "AT1G23190", "AT1G23310", "AT1G23800", 
"AT1G24100", "AT1G24180", "AT1G25220", "AT1G25350", "AT1G26230", 
"AT1G27680", "AT1G28350", "AT1G29880", "AT1G30120", "AT1G30510", 
"AT1G31180", "AT1G31230", "AT1G31860", "AT1G31910", "AT1G32440", 
"AT1G32550", "AT1G34430", "AT1G48030", "AT1G48520", "AT1G48850", 
"AT1G48860", "AT1G49760", "AT1G50200", "AT1G51680", "AT1G52340", 
"AT1G52400", "AT1G53240", "AT1G53580", "AT1G53830", "AT1G54100", 
"AT1G54220", "AT1G54490", "AT1G55490", "AT1G56190", "AT1G58080", 
"AT1G58290", "AT1G59900", "AT1G60550", "AT1G62180", "AT1G62660", 
"AT1G62800", "AT1G63970", "AT1G65060", "AT1G65700", "AT1G65930", 
"AT1G66430", "AT1G66520", "AT1G66530", "AT1G69740", "AT1G70290", 
"AT1G70580", "AT1G70730", "AT1G70980", "AT1G71920", "AT1G72330", 
"AT1G72550", "AT1G72810", "AT1G74030", "AT1G74040", "AT1G74090", 
"AT1G74100", "AT1G74470", "AT1G75330", "AT1G75660", "AT1G79230", 
"AT1G79550", "AT1G80560", "AT1G80600", "AT2G01140", "AT2G01290", 
"AT2G02500", "AT2G04400", "AT2G04842", "AT2G05710", "AT2G06990", 
"AT2G14750", "AT2G17130", "AT2G17265", "AT2G17510", "AT2G17630", 
"AT2G19940", "AT2G20420", "AT2G20610", "AT2G21170", "AT2G21330", 
"AT2G21590", "AT2G22250", "AT2G22480", "AT2G22780", "AT2G23350", 
"AT2G24490", "AT2G25355", "AT2G25840", "AT2G26540", "AT2G26670", 
"AT2G26930", "AT2G27150", "AT2G27820", "AT2G29560", "AT2G29630", 
"AT2G29690", "AT2G30970", "AT2G31170", "AT2G31390", "AT2G31810", 
"AT2G33210", "AT2G34630", "AT2G36230", "AT2G36390", "AT2G36460", 
"AT2G36530", "AT2G36580", "AT2G36880", "AT2G37500", "AT2G38700", 
"AT2G39800", "AT2G40300", "AT2G40490", "AT2G40840", "AT2G42790", 
"AT2G43090", "AT2G43100", "AT2G43750", "AT2G43810", "AT2G44040", 
"AT2G44350", "AT2G44490", "AT2G45290", "AT2G45300", "AT2G45440", 
"AT2G45810", "AT2G47510", "AT3G01120", "AT3G01440", "AT3G02660", 
"AT3G02760", "AT3G02780", "AT3G03250", "AT3G03710", "AT3G03780", 
"AT3G04120", "AT3G04520", "AT3G04600", "AT3G04790", "AT3G04870", 
"AT3G04940", "AT3G06350", "AT3G06650", "AT3G07630", "AT3G08590", 
"AT3G09150", "AT3G09810", "AT3G10050"), class = "factor"), X1_1 = c(0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1.790289807, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2.55899547, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 9.167631809, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1.039532599, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2.445322589, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0)), .Names = c("X", "Pathway", "Gene.name", 
"X1_1"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -199L))
```

Desired output (just edited manually):

```
> data_met[,1:2]
                           Pathway Gene.name
3                    aa_metabolism AT1G01090
19                 RNA degradation AT1G07780
28  aa_metabolism, RNA degradation AT1G03130
33                               0 AT1G14810
34                 RNA degradation AT1G26230
35                               0 AT1G03630
```

and so on...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

May be you need

```
data_met$Pathway[data_met$Gene.name %in% a] <- 'aa_metabolism'
```

#### Update

In the example data, the `Gene.name` elements don't have a match with `a`.  Suppose, the column has some elements in `a`.

```
 data_met$Gene.name <- as.character(data_met$Gene.name)
 data_met$Gene.name[2] <- as.character(a[2])
 data_met$Gene.name[4] <- as.character(a[7])
```

When we compare with the `a` vector ie. the first vector, replace the elements as before

```
 data_met$Pathway[data_met$Gene.name %in% a] <- 'aa_metabolism'
```

Creating a second vector `a1`

```
 a1 <- a[1:6]
 data_met$Gene.name[5] <- as.character(a1[3])

 data_met$Pathway <- with(data_met, ifelse(Gene.name %in% a1 & Pathway!=0,
            paste(Pathway, 'new_metabolism', sep=","),
           ifelse(Gene.name %in% a1 & Pathway==0, 'new_metabolism', Pathway)))
```

For the new dataset,

```
tbl_test$Pathway[tbl_test$Gene.name %in% aa] <- 'aa_metabolism'
tbl_test$Pathway <- with(tbl_test, ifelse(Gene.name %in% 
        rnadegrad & Pathway!=0,paste(Pathway, 'RNA_degradation', sep=","),
       ifelse(Gene.name %in% rnadegrad & Pathway==0,
                            'RNA_degradation', Pathway)))
```

Comment: That's amazing. It is what I am looking for but I would like to do it couple of times with different vectors of genes and different word. Is it possible to put two words in cell because I believe if any of genes will be repeated it will just put new word, not leave the first one and put the second after for example coma. Possible to do ?

Comment: Sorry for bothering but I found that something is not ok in this code. For the second vector it changes the column `Gene.name` to full of 0 and some with the name of `'new_metabolism'`. I would like to change only column `Pathway`. As I saw it's working good because it's adding new metabolism after coma but changing the other column is not ok :). Thx again!

Comment: @ShaxiLiver  Sorry, I should have assigned it to `data_met$Pathway <- ` instead of `data_met$Gene.name <- `.  Please check if that is what you wanted or else do post a small example and the expected output.

Comment: @akrun-> there is nothing to apologise I could easly figure it out on my own but it was really late for me yesterday. It's not working perfectly yet but we are close. It removes the first metabolism and just keep the second metabolism and the genes which works in both metabolism. I would like keep first and second metabolism as a single and when gene works for both. I edited my question with second metabolism and a bit bigger main table (called `data_met` previously, now it's `tbl_test`). I put desired output as well. Thx once again!

Comment: @ShaxiLiver  In the `data_met` none of the `Gene.name` matches `a`.  I assume in your expected output, you changed some values in `a`?   For example `data_met$Gene.name %in% a#[1] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE` and `data_met$Gene.name %in% rnadegrad#[1] FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE`.  Here, the fourth entry is `TRUE`  But in the expected, it is 0.

Comment: yeah, that's why I put `tbl_test` now instead of `data_met`. It was just part of my data and it might be the reason why we couldn't find any match. Now you can use `a` and `tbl_test`. Should be fine.

Comment: @ShaxiLiver Even in the `tbl_test$Gene.name %in% a` atleast the first 30 or so are FALSE.  Is that expected.

Comment: Sorry!! once again! Edited my question. It's a vector `aa` not `a`... sorry again

Comment: @ShaxiLiver  I think I got it.  Yesterday, it was late for me also, when I tried this (sleepy):-)

Comment: Great, w8ing for the edited answer! I really appreciate the work you did.

Comment: Perfect. Exactly what I was looking for. Amazing work you did!

Comment: @ShaxiLiver  No problem.  I did change the `new_metabolism` to `RNA_degradation`.